# How to sort the Object containing list in asc order

Tags: java

i want to get the data from list in asc order..

```
List<Region> region = (List<Region>) model.get("region");
```

if i am using `Collection.sort(region);`

then showing this,
The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List)

Comment: Does your `Region` class implement a `Comparable` interface?

Comment: No.. it is basically a model class whose contains the database value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the class `Region` as `Comparable` or you need to pass an additional parameter of type `Comparator` to the sort method.

Without a `Comparator` the [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) is

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)[1]
```

and the javadoc explicitly said that the class must implements Comparable:

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. **All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface**. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

in this case you need to modify your code as follow:

```
public class Region implements Comparable {

    public int compareTo(Region o) {
       // Add the logic to compare regions here.
    }

    ... 
}
```

The second version with a `Comparator` has the following [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)):

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

and all the elements must be comparable using the passed Comparator:

> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator. **All elements in the list must be mutually comparable using the specified comparator** (that is, c.compare(e1, e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

In this case you need to change your code directly calling the sort method as follow:

```
Collections.sort(regionList, (Region r1, Region r2)-> {
    // Add compare logic here
});
```

Note: there is an additional little mistake in your code the class to use is Collections (with an s) and not the interface Collection. I also changed the name of the list from region to regionList (eventually name it regions) because it is not only a single element but it is a list.

Comment: can you please show you answer in any sample of code.

Answer (score 1):

Custom comparator in a line for your code,

```
List<Region> region = (List<Region>) model.get("region");
Collections.sort(region, new Comparator<Region>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(Region a1, Region a2) {
    return a1.getType().compareToIgnoreCase(a2.getType()); //You can alter this condition based on your condition to compare
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the sorting to the database query.

As it seems the values should be unique, you could also have as model a `SortedSet`, implementing class: `TreeSet`.

Comment: Who said that there is a database?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO See mohit's comment _"it is basically a model class whose contains the **database** value"_

Comment: You can't say that. It is possible for example to have the data in memory and you can order them there. You can retrieve them from a call to a web service that has no capabilities to sort them, you can retrieve them from a file, it is possible also that the data are added usign a form.

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO indeed, (1) sorting in the database, or (2) using a SortedSet, might both be impossible. But I would first start at the root: database: let it do its work itself, then the model: right datastructure, data ordered. And last do a `list.sort(...)` oneself. That would be cleanest IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

i done with it...

```
Collections.sort(region, new Comparator<Region>() {
            public int compare(Region obj1, Region obj2) {
                return obj1.getStrRegion().compareTo(obj2.getStrRegion());
            }
        });
```